# Putting two Linq query data into two separate datatable columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, multiple-columns

I’m a newbie with linq and have been stuck for a few days on a this issue. Below is the xml for my example.

<

```
                    <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="IG_TABLE_MODALITYTABLE" ItemGroupRepeatKey="1" TransactionType="Insert">
                        <ItemData ItemOID="I_TABLE_MODAL_DATE_TABLE" Value="2014-05-01" />
                        <ItemData ItemOID="I_TABLE_MODAL_TYPE_TABLE" Value="1" />
                    </ItemGroupData>
                    <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="IG_TABLE_MODALITYTABLE" ItemGroupRepeatKey="2" TransactionType="Insert">
                        <ItemData ItemOID="I_TABLE_MODAL_DATE_TABLE" Value="2014-05-02" />
                        <ItemData ItemOID="I_TABLE_MODAL_TYPE_TABLE" Value="2" />
                    </ItemGroupData>
```

What I’m trying to achieve is to differentiate ItemData into DATE and TYPE and then put it into a datatable column that has been created. Below is my current attempt which only concatenates the rows rather than put the data into two created columns . Thank you so much for your help. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

```
            DataTable modDt = new DataTable();
            modDt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(string)));
            modDt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type", typeof(string))); //changed to string?

            var document = XDocument.Load("doc.xml");

            XNamespace nsSys = "http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3";

             //Get nodes separated by inner child element
             var values = document.Descendants(nsSys + "ItemData")
            .Where(t => t.Attribute("ItemOID").Value == "I_TABLE_MODAL_DATE_TABLE")
            .Select(x => x.Attribute("Value").Value);

             foreach (var item in values)
             {
                 modDt.Rows.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(item, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yy"),null);
             }


             var typevalues = document.Descendants(nsSys + "ItemData")
             .Where(t => t.Attribute("ItemOID").Value == "I_TABLE_MODAL_TYPE_TABLE")
             .Select(x => x.Attribute("Value").Value);

             foreach (var item in typevalues)
             {
                 modDt.Rows.Add(null ,int.Parse(item));
             }

             foreach (DataRow row in modDt.Rows)
             {
                 string sessionDate = row["Date"].ToString();
                 string mod = row["Type"].ToString();

                 string xnatCli = mod + sessionDate;
                 Console.Write(xnatCli);
             }

             Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some assumptions in your code that the I_TABLE_MODAL_DATE_TABLE and I_TABLE_MODAL_TYPE_TABLE will always match up.  The code I posted does an extra check to make sure that's a correct assumption.  Also groups them so we get a row for each valid ItemGroupData.  If one of the attributes are missing it just adds the valid one if both are missing it skips that row.  Also if there are multiple attributes with the same name the code just takes the last one in the ItemGroupData.

```
var modDt = new DataTable();
modDt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime)));
modDt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type", typeof(int))); 

var document = XDocument.Load("doc.xml");

XNamespace nsSys = "http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3";

//Get ItemData attributes group by the itemGroupData
var itemGroupDatas =
    document.Descendants(XName.Get("ItemGroupData", nsSys.NamespaceName))
            .Elements(XName.Get("ItemData", nsSys.NamespaceName))
            .Select(x => new
                {
                    itemOID = x.Attribute(XName.Get("ItemOID")),
                    value = x.Attribute(XName.Get("Value"))
                })

            .Where(
                x =>
                x.itemOID != null && x.value != null &&
                (x.itemOID.Value == "I_TABLE_MODAL_DATE_TABLE" ||
                 x.itemOID.Value == "I_TABLE_MODAL_TYPE_TABLE"))
            .GroupBy(x => x.itemOID.Parent.Parent, x => x);

foreach (var itemGroupData in itemGroupDatas)
{
    // record per each group
    var row = modDt.NewRow();
    foreach (var itemData in itemGroupData)
    {
        if (itemData.itemOID.Value == "I_TABLE_MODAL_DATE_TABLE")
        {
            DateTime date;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(itemData.value.Value, out date))
            {
                row["Date"] = date;
            }
        }
        if (itemData.itemOID.Value == "I_TABLE_MODAL_TYPE_TABLE")
        {
            int type;
            if (int.TryParse(itemData.value.Value, out type))
            {
                row["Type"] = type;
            }
        }
    }
    modDt.Rows.Add(row);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Cheers for your solution. it's a very good solution. However the dates i get are slightly off. It gives me. 01/05/2014 00:00:00 and 02/05/2014 00:00:00. I wanted to get 05/01/14 and 02/05/14. Cheers.

Comment: C# doesn't have just a Date type.  It's always DateTime.  if you want just the date part you can convert it to a string by doing date.ToShortDateString().